# Android CardView custom background

Tags: android, android-cardview

In our chat app we have message layout. We want to implement new CardView for our message bubble. 
In image there is chat layout of Telegram app. You can see small triangle beside each message, is it possible to get same design with CardView?

[image]

Comment: No i think so you have to use image and give shadow and elevation to do like this also you can use shape

Comment: You could extend CardView and draw your own..

Comment: use some 9patch image creator tools. http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17542066/450534. This is however, **not used with the CardView widget**. This is a background for a `LinearLayout` (_in the code_) but can just as easily be used for a `TextView`. There a few links attached that could be of help getting the _perfect_ speech bubble.