# How to add the Image at the end of Textview Android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to build Whatsapp like Chat bubble, for that I used TextView with `android:drawableRight`.

But chat bubble is inside the TextView(but at right side), below is the chat bubble image.

[image]

And TextView is

```
         <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:maxWidth="200dp"
           android:text="Some text"
           android:drawableRight="@drawable/bubble"
           android:drawableEnd="@drawable/bubble"
           android:padding="8dp"
           android:background="#dcf8c6"
          />
```

How I can add chat bubble as tail for TextView which will exactly look like WhatsApp chat bubble.

Finally It should look like

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to put the image? right side or bottom or what?

Comment: you should use nine-patch images for this

Comment: @GM.Akbar Thank you for the reply, I just added the image how it should look like.

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti I think you should create *nine patch image* as of same image and use it as a *background*.

Comment: For this issue I think you should not use image use some boxes with some styles.

Comment: go through with this reference for chat bubble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541739/how-to-add-the-bubbles-to-textview-android

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti i have posted answer try it. its help you

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti you should use a Ninepatch image... If you do not want to get into that trouble, use the answer i gave.. you will have to tweak the margins a little as i am not on android studio, i can't see the result...

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bubble_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxEms="12"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hi! new message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In following code bubble1 is **.9.patch** image with tails which you want.

for more see this link [chat with bubble](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-1/)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to create 9 patch Image for chat Bubble I uploaded in question. 9 Patch tool at https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti right click on image then you can get create 9patch file

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti right click drawable image > Create 9patch file

Answer (score 1):

Use 9 patch instead of using image as background or else to textView to show bubble, nine patch is better...,  refer this tutorial to how to create `9-PATCH` image 
[9patch Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

To generate 9patch online click [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp actually uses a NinePatch image to make the custom shape. If you insist on using this, you can use something like:

```
     <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

       <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:maxWidth="200dp"
       android:text="Some text"
       android:padding="8dp"
       android:background="#dcf8c6"
       />

       <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview"
       android:background="@drawable/bubble"
       />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti this is a hacky alternative to your question...Ideally use a 9patch...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 9patch image for your bubble image. image extention is .9.png. you can check [this](http://findnerd.com/account/#url=/list/view/How-to-create-9Patch-Image/15208/) link for study about 9patch image. or you can create online 9patch imasge from [here](http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top[]=25&top[]=50&right[]=25&right[]=50&bottom[]=25&bottom[]=50&left[]=25&left[]=50).

Answer (score -1):

you can use `android:drawableBottom=""` to add image to bottom of textview